Not able to connect Power BI with Dataverse
While connecting the Dataverse table with Power BI I get the below error-
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
ErrorCode=-2146232060
Number=121
Class=20
State=0

I am new to Power Apps, I tried to play around the connection settings but couldn't find anything relevant

It looks like this may answer your issue:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-268-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake/ba-p/3708542
